# Как протестировать в Unittest функцию в twig

Tags: symfony2, twig, phpunit

Сделал функцию в getUtl в (Twig_Extension) как написать phpunit test для нее, раньше тесты если и писал то такие же как в большинстве примеров, где сравниваются входные данные с результатом. Натолкните где хотя бы почитать.

Answer (score 1):

Ваш TwigExtension должен делегировать выполнение всей работы в какой-либо сервис, который, в свою очередь, будет протестирован вами.